# Overriding C++ template function in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, stack, calling-convention

I am trying to write a stack that returns the minimum element of the stack in O(1), for that I am using a derived class but not getting successful. I am getting an error when trying to call the base class's function from derived class. Would appreciate if you can review the code and provide any input on how to fix it. SCREENSHOT OF ERROR : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBGjG.jpg

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 999999

int findmin(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return a;
    return b;
}
class nodeWithMin
{
public:
    int val, min;
    nodeWithMin(int x, int y)
    {
        val = x;
        min = y;
    }
};
class myStack : public stack<nodeWithMin>
{
public:
    void push(int dat) 
    {
        int newMin = findmin(dat, stackMin());
        stack<nodeWithMin>::push(new nodeWithMin(dat, newMin));
    }
    int stackMin()
    {
        if (this->empty())
            return MAX;
        else
            return this->top().min;
    }
};
```

Comment: provide the error please

Comment: updated with the error message. can you please check now.

Comment: include the error msg / picture on stackoverflow by uploading the img here as your upload may become invalid at some point.

Comment: I am not allowed to embed a picture as I am yet to get 10 reps or something. So, I edited the post and included a hyperlink to the screenshot. Here it's again. http://imgur.com/PhoNRpq Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change this:

```
stack<nodeWithMin>::push(new nodeWithMin(dat, newMin));
```

to:

```
stack<nodeWithMin>::push(nodeWithMin(dat, newMin));
```

Comment: Actualy, you may consider replacing `int newMin = findmin(dat, stackMin());` to `newMin = dat < newMin ? dat : newMin` and make `newMin` a private variable of `myStack` class

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That would really make it more compact :)